# Org-mode lists and org-babel "shortcuts" are not working properly

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I started using Emacs about a month, and I began to make my configuration yesterday. Everything works fine, but I have some problems with `org-mode` lists.

When I create a new list and then press `RET` or `C-m`, this is what happens:
[image]

instead of creating a new line with `-` aligned to the upper line. Also, when I type `<el` it doesn't make an Elisp source block. How can I get this working?

I'm on Fedora Linux --- kernel 5.18.7; Emacs version: 27.2

Comment: To create a new item in a list, use `M-RET` - see [Plain Lists](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-Lists.html#Plain-Lists) in the Org mode manual. There is no `<el` entry by default in the termplate expansion mechanism (which you have to activate with `(require 'org-tempo)` ) - maybe you mean `<s` - although you have to fill in the language manually. You can define your own entries: see [Structure Templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I had to use `M-RET` to create a new list item. Thanks!

How do I create a new list item with a check box too? Or do I have to add the check box manually? 

I added into my initial config the `(require 'org-tempo)` but nothing is happening when I use `<s tab`...

Comment: Did you read the `Plain Lists` page I referred you to? That answers your first and second questions. For the third question, are you in an Org mode buffer at the time? I did `emacs -q` to start without an init file, I evaluated `(require 'org-tempo)` in the `*scratch*` buffer, I did `C-x C-f /tmp/foo.org` to create an Org mode buffer, I did `<s TAB` and I got a source block.

Comment: I got it. When I was opening the org file an error was occurring because I had a bad configuration of org-mode in my init file. Thank you @NickD !